# Cakephp Hash return key if sub value matches something

Tags: cakephp, hash

I've never really used the Cakephp Hash utility class, so sorry if this is a simple question. I'm reading the documentation online, and I'm not sure if I can do what I want.

Is there a way to use Hash to return one of the values along the path if a sub-value matches something. For example if I have an array

```
$test_array = [123 => ['name' => 'foo'], 234 => ['name' => 'bar']];
```

and I want to return 123 or 234 depending on what value of 'name' I test for, could I use something like the code below to get the key?

```
$return_value = Hash::extract($test_array, '{n}.[text=/foo/]');
```

Comment: hash is deprecated. What version of cakephp are you using?

Comment: @arilia Hash is deprecated? Since when? It makes no mention of that in the current 3.5 book: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html

Comment: you're right, sorry. I thought that Collections deprecated Hash but I see that both are still there

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself, It's not quite as flexible as I'd like, but it works for my particular case.

```
//initial array
$test_array = [123 => ['name' => 'foo'], 234 => ['name' => 'bar']];

//convert to collection
$test_collection = collection($test_array);

//filter collection to get only what we want
$collection_filtered = $test_collection->match(['name' => 'bar']);

//convert collection back to array [234 => ['name' => 'bar']]
$collection_to_array = $collection_filtered->toArray();

//use php functions array_keys() and reset() to get the appropriate value
$key = reset(array_keys($collection_to_array));

echo $key; //$key = 234

//can also be written in one line like so
$key = reset(array_keys(collection($test_array)->match(['name' => 'bar'])->toArray()));
```